# spring-boot, spring security, spring web with maven, jboss and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, jboss, spring-boot

I have read many tutorials including the official Spring documentation but unable to create a project which works with the following requirements.

1. Dynamic web project with Maven (Spring MVC with Spring Security implemented)
2. No XMLs should be used. (Fully annotated with Spring Boot)
3. IDE:Eclipse and without the use of command-line.
4. Should be deployable to JBOSS AS.

Edit: I have configured the project and tried running it using Run->Maven clean and Run->Maven build (clean and install goals)..

I can see the thymeleaf html files in the war file but when I hit the url for the thymeleaf html files, the spring tags in the page are not resolved and displayed as such.
Static html pages are loaded fine though.

PS: There are no errors in the console.

Comment: Can you add more details? Display stuff that you tried, provide some error messages?

Comment: It would be helpful if a tutorial link can be suggested for this.

Comment: Questions asking for tutorials are considered off-topic. Also what you have should work, also I strongly would suggest a read of the Spring Boot reference which explains how to run a Spring Boot application on an external server.